# Track external search form in Google Analytics/GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We have a search box on our website that searches a product we subscribe to.  It's hosted on the third party's server, not on our domain.

Since it's just embedded on our site, I can't use Google Analtyics' built in configuration for tracking site search.

Is there another way I can track the terms used to search in the form, using either Google Analytics/Tag Manager?

Comment: "Embedded" is not the most precise term. Can we assume that this search runs completely inside an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use GTM if the search query is entered on your site. Let's say, using a trigger on the search CTA click, you can then use a custom JS variable where you get the value of the search field using JS, use that variable in a GA event tag and there you have your value logged in GA.